# array sum in array php

Tags: php, arrays, sum

**Hi please help. how can sum this array**

```
Array
(
    [975] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 79.35
                    [1] => 14.28
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 79.35
                    [1] => 14.28
                )

        )

    [758] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16615.82
                    [1] => 2990.85
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16615.82
                    [1] => 2990.85
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 16615.82
                    [1] => 2990.85
                )
        )
)
```

**Resul look like**

```
Array
(
    [975] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 158.7
                    [1] => 28.56
                )
        )

    [758] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 49847.46
                    [1] => 8972.55
                )
        )

)
```

Comment: share your code in addition to your arrays. Add it to your post.

Comment: SO I wrote help, mr Barmar. its not for comersial

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create a separate array then loop through the nested array and add them individually. If you cannot perform that then you shouldn't be writing code in PHP ;)